# Many to many realationship and join in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have following three models

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :dob, :mobile
  has_many :books, :through => 'ratings'
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :book_name, :author, :pages
  has_many :users, :through => 'ratings'
end
```

Now I have to find all the "book_name"s of each book which is related the respective user and store it in the array.

Here is code

```
@book_names = []
@books = Rating.find(:all, 'user_id = ?', current_user.id)
@books.each do |book|
  book_info = Book.find(book.id)
  @book_names << book_info.book_name
end
```

Is there any other way for the same or join method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is simple way to do it. Try

```
@book_names= current_user.books.map(&:book_name)
```